# How to add sum of rows of a matrix into vector?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

Since the question would be a bit long, ill add that here, I also want to add a row in a vector to the Finald vector.

```
MatrixXf ProdA(7, 7);;
VectorXf Intd(7);
VectorXf Finald(7);
ProdA << 
    7, 5, 1, 9, 11, 2, 0,
    5, 2, 8, 3, 11, 3, 3,
    3, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 7,
    6, 0, 1, 9, 11, 33, 3,
    3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3,
    3, 9, 1, 1, 0, 1, 15,
    6, 2, 6, 2, 5, 12, 3,

Intd << 4, 5, 2, 12, 4, 1, 6;

Finald << 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    Finald.row(i) += ProdA.rowwise().sum();
        Finald.row(i) += Intd.row(i);
}
```

So far this is what I have got. Obviously I get an error if I put i in rowwise. So as an example, I want to add the first row of ProdA , and the first number of Intd into the first space in the Finald vector, and then loop through every row of ProdA and Intd, and sum them all into Finald.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% certain that I correctly understand your problem, but the way I understood it, this should work:

```
VectorXf ones(7);
ones << 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;

Finald = ProdA * ones + Intd;
```

I'm not sure if your matrix library (which seems to be Eigen) stores vectors as row or column vectors. So you might have to use `ones.transpose()` instead.

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123 If an answer answers your question, please mark it as accepted. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: I am being downvoted even though it seems to be the right answer?